# domain whitelist in cordova Android appears to be ignored

Tags: android, cordova

I've downloaded a fresh copy of Phonegap 2.5, and created a new project as per the instructions [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android).

I then edited /res/xml/config.xml to whitelist all domains:

```
<cordova>
  <access origin=".*" subdomains="true" />
  <log level="DEBUG"/>
... etc (nothing changed beyond this point) ...
```

when I try to retrieve any external page via jQuery's $.ajax() function, though, the function fails. LogCat doesn't even show that the download was attempted at all.

Wifi is enabled, and the phone can access websites using its browser.

any ideas?

FURTHER INFORMATION

I've noticed this error in the log:

```
04-10 12:37:28.007: E/dalvikvm(2074): Could not find class 'android.webkit.WebResourceResponse', referenced from method org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.getWhitelistResponse
```

I've found posts elsewhere that say that "WebResourceResponse" errors should be ignored, but this appears to be directly related to my problem (see the getWhitelistResponse part)

Comment: If it was a whitelist issue, Cordova would show that the URL was blacklisted and it would have told you to check your whitelist.  Is it possible that the request isn't being called?

Comment: I don't know what's going on with the Java but in the JavaScript, the xmlhttprequest is definitely being run it comes back with an error, but no useful explanation of the error. The server shows no sign of being accessed in the logs

Comment: Try taking jQuery out of the equation and do a raw XmlHttpRequest. Sometimes jQuery needs to have cors flags set in order to make the cross request.

Comment: Is it with status=0? You may have to add something stupid like a Math.random() in your query string to get past Android WebView's caching.  But I agree with Simon, turf jQuery and do a raw XmlHttpRequest.

Comment: I figured it out in the end. not intuitive, but it appears to be correct. It turns out the Cordova was OK.

The problem was that I was doing the Ajax query as a result of a click on a button element which was contained in a form element. Because I didn't "return false;" at the end of the event, the form cancelled the Ajax query and reloaded the page, but so quick that I didn't see the reload.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be unrelated to Cordova. The Ajax call was initiated as a click event on a button which was contained in a form element. Because I forgot to "return false;" on the event, the click event bubbled up and triggered a submit on the form. The form had no target, so simply reloaded the page. The whole thing was so fast that it *appeared* as if the Ajax request simply failed.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer in future.